# Twitter limits & multiple users using shared account

Tags: asp.net, twitter, twitterizer

I'm building a section of a web app that will integrate with twitter (using twitterizer) and I"m not sure I fully understand how the twitter limits will apply. Let me explain.

Most of my users will have one account (.e.g @ServiceAssistance) that will be shared by multiple 'application' users. Each user will login to the app and start monitoring mentions, hashtags, DMs etc all for the same a/c. For now I'm only getting new tweets since the first load using a timer every 60 seconds.

So the question now is if 10 users are monitoring the feed, that means within a 30 min they'll have passed the 350 rate limit. Is there a best practice that I'm not aware of or is there something that I can do to prevent my app hitting the limit?

Also, I've been thinking of having each 'application' user authorise and get a different TokenSecret (i.e. not share access but each have individual access), but I noticed that the Accesstoken and TokenSecret given out are the same as long as you're requesting access to the same twitter account from the same app.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem by saving all tweets to a table, then all users read from that table. Problem solved.